# Azure website very slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

[image]My web app is very slow at certain times and ok during other times. I have been using the cloud services for 2 years and never I faced this problem. I can understand if its slow at all times. I have a staging and production instance. The staging site is fast always.

I have started facing this problem from 2 days when there was a service outage from Azure in North Europe area and thereafter the performance has worsened. I have tried rebooting the instance after the outage was resolved and web app performance was looking fine for some time. Now back to bad performance.I am presuming its got something to do with azure since at times everythign works fine. Pls help. Pls let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Impossible to help, since you don't provide *any* information. Azure provides a *lot* of metrics, performance counters, alerts etc. DId you check them? Do you experience heavier traffic? Have you deployed code that resulted in slower execution? Are you using a small instance? Do you have any logs? Have you installed Application Insights? What does it report?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Pls see the screen added. Pls let  me know if this is enough. Yes we do have an  small instance. I dont believe there was unusally heavy traffic. But I attributed the performance issue due to the Azure service outage issue that affected North Europe.

Comment: No, it's not enough - you should check *ASP.NET* performance counters, like requests/sec, memory allocations etc. And no, the outage info is irrelevant, just as it would be irrelevant if you hosted the site locally. In fact, troubleshooting a web site's problems is the same whether it's hosted or not. You need to check logs, performance counters, check increased traffic etc. There are guides how to do this, Azure also provides relevant tools (like Application Insights). A simple screenshot can't show all the required info

Comment: Thanks for giving me direction. I was using an extra small instance and there were areas that were memory intensive . I changed the instance to a small and could see drastic improvement in the speed. Since you have replied to my question and not answered I cannot accept the answer. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of scenarios where you don't know where the problem might be, I'd advice to setup a [free NewRelic account](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-preview-portal) on Azure and activate the extension on your Web App.

[NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/home-t1) will tell you, transaction by transaction and resource by resource where your bottlenecks might be or your code problems.